Unable to save entities in one-to-many relationship using joined inheritance
I am getting this error when try to save order for a buyer and no matter what i do,its keep on giving this error; I have attached my db model for reference.

buyer is a person and implemented using joined inheritance
buyer can have many orders, each order can have many line items
items have specific inventory for each business, during order processig its checeked

Please help if my relationships are not right.
   2024-04-03T01:02:20.761+01:00  INFO 15396 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.k.t.buyer.controller.BuyerController   : creating/updating a new buyer order {} : 
Hibernate: select b1_0.person_id,b1_1.person_id,b1_1.date_of_birth,b1_1.first_name,b1_1.gender,b1_1.id_number,b1_1.last_name,b1_1.title,b1_0.business_name,b1_0.buyer_note,b1_0.buyer_username from buyer b1_0 join person b1_1 on b1_0.person_id=b1_1.person_id where b1_0.buyer_username=?
Hibernate: select i1_0.business_id,i1_0.item_id,i1_0.available_quantity,b1_0.business_id,a1_0.account_id,a1_0.account_number,a1_0.account_status,a1_0.current_balance,a1_0.opening_balance,a1_0.opening_date,b1_0.business_entity_type,b1_0.business_name,b1_0.business_trade_type,b1_0.registration_date,i1_0.comments,i2_0.item_id,i2_0.available_quantity,i2_0.currency,i2_0.item_number,i2_0.item_title,i2_0.purchased_quantity,i2_0.sku,i2_0.sold_quantity,i2_0.unit_price,i1_0.units,i1_0.update_date,i1_0.update_quantity from inventory i1_0 join business b1_0 on b1_0.business_id=i1_0.business_id left join account a1_0 on a1_0.account_id=b1_0.account_id join item i2_0 on i2_0.item_id=i1_0.item_id where (i1_0.business_id,i1_0.item_id) in ((?,?))
Hibernate: select i1_0.business_id,i1_0.item_id,i1_0.available_quantity,b1_0.business_id,a1_0.account_id,a1_0.account_number,a1_0.account_status,a1_0.current_balance,a1_0.opening_balance,a1_0.opening_date,b1_0.business_entity_type,b1_0.business_name,b1_0.business_trade_type,b1_0.registration_date,i1_0.comments,i2_0.item_id,i2_0.available_quantity,i2_0.currency,i2_0.item_number,i2_0.item_title,i2_0.purchased_quantity,i2_0.sku,i2_0.sold_quantity,i2_0.unit_price,i1_0.units,i1_0.update_date,i1_0.update_quantity from inventory i1_0 join business b1_0 on b1_0.business_id=i1_0.business_id left join account a1_0 on a1_0.account_id=b1_0.account_id join item i2_0 on i2_0.item_id=i1_0.item_id where (i1_0.business_id,i1_0.item_id) in ((?,?))
Hibernate: select o1_0.buyer_id,o1_0.order_id,o1_0.order_date,o1_0.order_number,o1_0.order_source,o1_0.order_status,o1_0.order_total,o1_0.order_type,o1_0.payment_status from order o1_0 where o1_0.buyer_id=?
2024-04-03T01:02:21.175+01:00  WARN 15396 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
2024-04-03T01:02:21.176+01:00 ERROR 15396 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order o1_0 where o1_0.buyer_id=5' at line 1
2024-04-03T01:02:21.183+01:00 ERROR 15396 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select o1_0.buyer_id,o1_0.order_id,o1_0.order_date,o1_0.order_number,o1_0.order_source,o1_0.order_status,o1_0.order_total,o1_0.order_type,o1_0.payment_status from order o1_0 where o1_0.buyer_id=?] [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order o1_0 where o1_0.buyer_id=5' at line 1] [n/a]] with root cause

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order o1_0 where o1_0.buyer_id=5' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:121) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at 

BuyerServiceImpl
    public BuyerOrdersResponseDTO addOrders(AddUpdateOrderToBuyerRequestDTO requestDTO) throws ResourceFoundException, ResourceNotFoundException {

        Buyer buyer = buyerRepository.findByUsername(requestDTO.getBuyerUsername());

        for (OrderDTO o : requestDTO.getOrders()) {
            Order order = getOrder(o);

            for (LineItemDTO li : o.getLineItems()) {
                LineItem lineItem = getLineItem(li);

                Optional<Inventory> optional = inventoryRepository.findById(new InventoryKey(li.getBusinessId(), li.getItemId()));
                if (optional.isPresent()) {
                    lineItem.setInventory(optional.get());
                }
                order.addLineItem(lineItem);
            }
            buyer.addOrder(order);
        }
        return orderMapper.apply(buyerRepository.save(buyer));
    }

Buyer Class
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "buyer")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "person_id")
public class Buyer extends Person {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "buyer_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "buyer_username")
private String buyerUsername;
@Column(name = "business_name")
private String businessName;  //if a buyer is a business customer
@Column(name = "buyer_note")
private String buyerNote;

@OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "buyer",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
)
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Order> orders = new HashSet<>();

public void addOrder(Order order) {
    orders.add(order);
    order.setBuyer(this);
}
public void removeOrder(Order order) {
    orders.remove(order);
    order.setBuyer(null);
    }
}

Order Class
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Order {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "order_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Long id;

private LocalDateTime orderDate;
private String orderNumber;
private OrderType orderType;
private OrderStatus orderStatus;
private OrderSource orderSource;
private BigDecimal orderTotal;
private PaymentStatus paymentStatus;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "buyer_id", nullable = false)
@JsonIgnore
private Buyer buyer;

@OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "order",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
)
@JsonIgnore
private Set<LineItem> lineItems = new HashSet<>();

public void addLineItem(LineItem lineItem) {
    lineItems.add(lineItem);
    lineItem.setOrder(this);
}

public void removeLineItem(LineItem lineItem) {
    lineItems.remove(lineItem);
    lineItem.setOrder(null);
    }

}

Line Items
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class LineItem {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "line_item_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Long id;

private Integer lineQuantity;
private Float lineDiscount;
private Float lineTotal;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(
                name = "business_id",
                referencedColumnName = "business_id"),
        @JoinColumn(
                name = "item_id",
                referencedColumnName = "item_id")
})
@JsonIgnore
private Inventory inventory;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "order_id", nullable = false)
@JsonIgnore
private Order order;
}

db model

I'm afraid you the actual root cause is using SQL reserved word order in table naming, rename it to orders or something like.

oh silly me, Thanks it fixed this issue now.
